# Have I obtained the correct simplified expression?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Have I obtained the correct simplified transfer function expression?

I am trying to obtain a transfer function for an electrical circuit. However, the response of the TF that I obtain doesn't correlate to the response of the circuit itself when I simulate it.

Therefore, I have obviously done something wrong in my derivation. I have spent a good couples of days and plenty of scrap papers trying to see where I have missed something, but I keep on arriving at the same answer.

So, in order save myself the headache of repeatedly doing the same thing only to obtain the same outcome, I've decided to put my dilemma to the community!

Below is my working out from the mid-way point to the end result and if anyone can point out what I have missed, I would really appreciate it.

So the starting expression is:

$$ I_2(s)((\frac{C_2Ls^2+C_2(R_1+R_2)s+1}{C_2Ls^2+C_2R_1s})(\frac{C_1Ls^2+C_1R_1s+1}{C_1s}))-I_2(s)(Ls+R_1)=E_i(s)\tag{1} $$

$$ I_2(s)((\frac{C_2Ls^2+C_2(R_1+R_2)s+1}{C_2Ls^2+C_2R_1s})(\frac{C_1Ls^2+C_1R_1s+1}{C_1s})-(Ls+R_1))=E_i(s) $$

$$ I_2(s)(\frac{(C_2Ls^2+C_2(R_1+R_2)s+1)({C_1Ls^2+C_1R_1s+1})}{(C_2Ls^2+C_2R_1s)(C_1s)})-(Ls+R_1))=E_i(s) $$

$$ I_2(s)(\frac{(C_2Ls^2+C_2(R_1+R_2)s+1)(C_1Ls^2+C_1R_1s+1)-(C_1C_2Ls^3+C_1C_2R_1s^2)(Ls+R_1)}{(C_1C_2Ls^3+C_1C_2R_1s^2)})\tag{2}$$

Expanding the numerator for the positive term

$$ (C_2Ls^2+C_2(R_1+R_2)s+1)(C_1Ls^2+C_1R_1s+1)$$

$$ (C_2Ls^2)(C_1Ls^2) + (C_2Ls^2)(C_1R_1s) + (C_2Ls^2)(1) + (C_2(R_1+R_2)s)(C_1Ls^2) + (C_2(R_1+R_2)s)(C_1R_1s)+(C_2(R_1+R_2)s)(1)) + (1)(C_1Ls^2) + (1)(C_1R_1s) + (1)(1) $$

$$ (C_1C_2L^2s^4) + (C_1C_2R_1Ls^3) + (C_2Ls^2) + (C_1C_2L(R_1+R_2)s^3) + (C_1C_2R_1(R_1+R_2)s^2) + C_2(R_1+R_2)s + (C_1Ls^2) + (C_1R_1s) + 1 $$

$$ C_1C_2L^2s^4 + C_1C_2R_1Ls^3 + C_2Ls^2 + C_1C_2L(R_1+R_2)s^3 + C_1C_2R_1(R_1+R_2)s^2 + C_2(R_1+R_2)s + C_1Ls^2 + C_1R_1s + 1 $$

$$ C_1C_2L^2s^4 + C_1C_2R_1Ls^3 + C_2Ls^2 + C_1C_2R_1Ls^3 + C_1C_2R_2Ls^3 + C_1C_2R_1^2s^2 + C_1C_2R_1R_2s^2 + C_2(R_1+R_2)s + C_1Ls^2 + C_1R_1s + 1 $$

$$ C_1C_2L^2s^4 + 2C_1C_2R_1Ls^3 + C_2Ls^2 + C_1C_2R_2Ls^3 + C_1C_2R_1^2s^2 + C_1C_2R_1R_2s^2 + C_2(R_1+R_2)s + C_1Ls^2 + C_1R_1s + 1 \tag{3}$$

Expanding the numerator for the negative term

$$ -(C_1C_2Ls^3+C_1C_2R_1s^2)(Ls+R_1)$$

$$ -((C_1C_2Ls^3)(Ls)+(C_1C_2Ls^3)(R_1)+(C_1C_2R_1s^2)(Ls)+(C_1C_2R_1s^2)(R_1))$$

$$ -(C_1C_2L^2s^4 + C_1C_2R_1Ls^3 + C_1C_2R_1Ls^3 + C_1C_2R_1^2s^2)\tag{4}$$

Subtracting $(4)$ from $(3)$

$$ C_1C_2L^2s^4 + 2C_1C_2R_1Ls^3 + C_2Ls^2 + C_1C_2R_2Ls^3 + C_1C_2R_1^2s^2 + C_1C_2R_1R_2s^2 + C_2(R_1+R_2)s + C_1Ls^2 + C_1R_1s + 1 -C_1C_2L^2s^4 - C_1C_2R_1Ls^3 - C_1C_2R_1Ls^3 - C_1C_2R_1^2s^2 $$

$$ C_1C_2L^2s^4 + 2C_1C_2R_1Ls^3 + C_2Ls^2 + C_1C_2R_2Ls^3 + C_1C_2R_1^2s^2 + C_1C_2R_1R_2s^2 + C_2(R_1+R_2)s + C_1Ls^2 + C_1R_1s + 1 - C_1C_2L^2s^4 - 2C_1C_2R_1Ls^3 - C_1C_2R_1^2s^2 $$

$$ C_2Ls^2 + C_1C_2R_2Ls^3 + C_1C_2R_1R_2s^2 + C_2(R_1+R_2)s + C_1Ls^2 + C_1R_1s + 1 $$

Combining like terms

$$ C_1C_2R_2Ls^3 + (C_1(C_2R_1R_2 + L)+ C_2L)s^2 + (C_2(R_1+R_2) + C_1R_1)s + 1 $$

Therefore, I get

$$ I_2(s)\frac{C_1C_2R_2Ls^3 + (C_1(C_2R_1R_2 + L)+ C_2L)s^2 + (C_2(R_1+R_2) + C_1R_1)s + 1}{C_1C_2Ls^3+C_1C_2R_1s^2} = E_i(s)$$

And I arrive at this final transfer function each and every time:

$$ \frac{I_2(s)}{E_i(s)}=\frac{C_1C_2Ls^3+C_1C_2R_1s^2}{C_1C_2R_2Ls^3 + (C_1(C_2R_1R_2 + L)+ C_2L)s^2 + (C_2(R_1+R_2) + C_1R_1)s + 1} \tag{5}$$

Therefore, if anyone has noted any step(s) that I might have missed, I would really appreciate it, if you could please point it out :)

Comment: Have you tried running it through a CAS (Computer Algebra System) already?

Comment: I tried using Matlab. But, it just churns out even more complicated algebra! What others would you recommend?

Comment: If you are confident that the starting expression is correct, as soon as you factor out $I_2(s)$ you can write your transfer function. No need to simplify anything, just verify that the function produces the correct results. If it does, there is an error somewhere in your simplifications.

Comment: @aLoHa I'm not that used to Matlab. I have used Mathematica and Maple. Fullsimplify on Mathematica works pretty well in my experience. Maple is not quite as effective but my experience is limited.

Comment: @Vasya I was quietly confident that my starting expression was correct, until I took your advice and tried to verify that the re-arranged expression produces the correct result. The good thing is that it is not far off; although it is not exact. So, I guess it's back to the drawing board. The good news is that you've provided me with another way to test and check my derivation. So thanks for that!

Comment: @Deepak, thanks for the heads up. I have heard of Mathematica. However, how intuitive is it to use?

Comment: @aLoHa I didn't find it difficult to learn, but according to the web it's supposed to be less intuitive than Matlab, so your mileage may vary (I just never bothered with Matlab at all so I can't compare them). And Vasya's advice is very sound, always test expressions. An additional piece of advice I will give you is this: when testing, with access to a calculator, use transcendental constants like $e$ and $\pi$ in preference to rational or algebraic irrationals to test algebraic expressions. Because you only achieve equality in the case of identity between the two expressions.

Comment: @Deepak thanks for the information and for the advice. However, it has been a long while since, I've done any Maths; so i'm still trying to find my feet tbh. But, I'll definitely keep it in my mind, going forward!

Comment: According to WolframAlpha, $(5)$ is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. So, I can rest assured that my derivation was on point!!

Comment: @Deepak, can you please elaborate the interesting advice? **when testing, with access to a calculator, use transcendental constants like e and π in preference to rational or algebraic irrationals to test algebraic expressions.**

Comment: @MathArt To be precise, I was referring to expressions without any transcendental coefficients (only algebraic ones). The OP was attempting to rearrange such an expression into another form. If the rearrangement is correct, this would basically be an identity. Every polynomial equation (that is not an identity) with algebraic coefficients can only have algebraic roots. Hence, if a transcendental constant solves such an equation, that has to be an identity (holding for all real and complex values). Within the limits of calculator error, this is one way to verify an algebraic identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  can confirm that my derivation was right. The issue that I had wasn't anything to do with my algebra, but my circuit analysis.

The final transfer function that I was actually after was $\dfrac{E_o(s)}{E_i(s)}$ and not $\dfrac{I_2(s)}{E_i(s)}$ which is what I had and that is why the response of the TF didn't correlate to the response of the circuit.